# to apply full text search in a given document and match a particular array in a member field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have a room schema(in mongoose) in which members id are stored in array and i want to apply full text search to find room names in which a given members are stored (using node.js and express).

eg:

```
var room = new Schema({
 name: {
 type: String,
 required: true
 },
 members: []``
});
```

I want to apply full text search to find a room name in which a particular member (provide through id) is stored.

Comment: you want to do a string search for the name of the room or search by ids (member ids) and the room will be returned ?

Comment: i want room names as a result in which a given members id is present or it(id) is in member array . can i get it by using full text search ? else how can i dot this search?